# Get specific timezone PHP

Tags: php, timezone

I have a zip_code database that also has the correct time zone associated with the zip code.  I store the users zip_code in a session and pull their time zone correctly like this:

```
$timezone_array = mysql_query("SELECT time_zone FROM zip_code WHERE zip_code = '".$zip_session."'");
while($timezone_cells = mysql_fetch_array($timezone_array))
{
    $their_timezone = $timezone_cells['time_zone'];
}
```

if my zip code is 07110, then `$their_timezone` will be Eastern. How do I use this with PHP to set the correct timezone? I cant figure out a way to use this function `date_default_timezone_set('America/new_york')` like this `date_default_timezone_set($their_timezone)`. the time_zones stored in the DB are Atlanic, Eastern, Central, Mountain, Pacific etc. Any function in PHP that can use these instead of nearest city ex: America/New_York?

Comment: pick 4 matching US cities, then use them for the date_default_timezone_set() function

Comment: maybe you should store the correct timezone in the db

Comment: **warning** your code maybe susceptible to sql injection attacks.

Comment: @daniel, i was just giving a quick example, sorry.

Comment: @lbu, it was a free DB of all US cities, zipcodes, lat, lon and their time_zones. Was hoping to use the already provided info.

Comment: US/Central, US/Eastern, US/Pacific are valid see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php

Comment: @Dagon ohh wow, I feel like a jerk, I never click on the "others" link thinking is was just other territories.

Comment: @Dagon if you throw that up as an answer, I'll gladly accept it so you can get the credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

US/Central, US/Eastern, US/Pacific are valid see:

[List of Supported Timezones:Other](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php)